# How can I join three list in one object in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to join three object list in one object with kotlin. But I don't know how to do it...

Some help will be appreciate.

This is my data class:

```
data class User(
    val address: Address,
    val company: Company,
    val email: String,
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val phone: String,
    val username: String,
    val website: String
)

data class Post(
    val body: String,
    val id: Int,
    val title: String,
    val userId: Int
)

data class Comment(
    val body: String,
    val email: String,
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val postId: Int
)
```

That I want to do is get one object like this if possible:

```
data class PostJoin(body: String, id: Int, title; String, user: User, comments: List<Comment>)
```

This is that I'm trying to do it, only can mix two objects but no how I want.

```
val postUsers = post.joinBy(users) { (post,user) -> post.userId == user.id }
                                    .map { PostViewModel(post = it.first, user = it.second) }

private inline fun <T : Any, U : Any> List<T>.joinBy(collection: List<U>, filter: (Pair<T, U>) -> Boolean): List<Pair<T, List<U>>> = map { t ->
        val filtered = collection.filter { filter(Pair(t, it)) }
        Pair(t, filtered)
    }
```

Comment: So I'm a tad confused by your question, you want to take a list of posts, users, and comments and combine them into a list of `PostJoin` ? What do your input lists look like? What should your expected output look like? In your example of what your trying to do, you use `PostViewModel`, whats a `PostViewModel`?

Comment: Yes, I want to combine this three list in one PostJoin the PostViewModel will be the PostJoin. I put the data class of my objects. Do you have some idea to how get it?

Comment: It looks like your post join would expect to have 1 user, 1 post and a list of comments, is this correct? How would your input lists look? Do you have a flat list of Users, Posts and Comments? If so how do you know which users go with what posts and what comments?

Comment: If you add an example of what an input may look like and what the expected output should look like I may be able to help more.

Comment: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts
 http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
 http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/commen

Comment: I paste you the three endpoints that I'm using. Post have the user id and comments hace the postid. And yes my joint post expext 1 post, 1 user and a lista of post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
val posts: List<Post> 
val users: List<User>
val comments: List<Comment>

// initialize lists
...

val joinedPosts = posts.fold(ArrayList<PostJoin>()) { joinedPosts, post ->
    val postComments = comments.filter { it.postId == post.id }
    val user = users.first { it.id == post.userId } 

    joinedPosts.add(PostJoin(post.body, post.id, post.title, user, postComments))
    joinedPosts
}
```

Seems to work for me: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVLNToQwEL7zFBNOkLAka8KFuETjaY1Rk9UHqBTcamk30DUQw7PjtPzvLtHIqUz7/c3Mp1SciYYSRSDmpCjgtUhyxwL8vggHRkPYCuUNBUGyJISdypl4H6uHvRRD2XIta0L4LAs1Er5JWp3jz2QUU/yCzhHNbdu3Jyp3MssS8atQkhHG/6C/EBOjXJbXIe8lEwv68K@koRnGWIvbjEUID6xQ113kyHKb9CgAkwnHhe@Z2/6t9hfBBjj@PKWOmYm9k1mi9ihre7D2wH7RVvTZdWc@ehLtZkJiNqXFZYiygyBYXa2DwJ7AFyyPJP3c7LLUHGV5U1V@HHeOult4xHF0xgbqD2x3QnWSAulMWD@VnDq3eU6qIbWeSuS42JgpwjMAWEWGbtqxTlJz9ub9lHGV5MjAlN/uAGxaSZ9RqGccumGINX1DYI4qBsdGTLvFUIM1ICfWfEKpM@yTAehd8nq97mD2xjM63sx41/0TVlOrW8EDrppyJpeuVTfNDw). Though I did give a pretty lazy input.